# Utilize array data saved in TXT file ( PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, text, fopen, file-get-contents

I am trying to utilize the data saved to list.txt via form submit and display it randomly on page.

index.php

```php
<?php
    //$list = file_get_contents('list.txt'); //Tested without fopen

    $myfile = fopen('list.txt', "r") or die ("");

    $list = fread($myfile,filesize('list.txt'));

    $bg0 = array($list ,'yellow'); // array of colors

    fclose($myfile);

    $i = rand(0, count($bg0)-1); // generate random number size of the array
    $selectedColor = "$bg0[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random color was chosen

    echo selectedColor;
?>
```

list.txt

```
'red', 'blue', 'green'
```

Comment: Which is your problem?

Comment: You need to make $list a real array by splitting the values.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to ask

Comment: Does not work. I understand the concept. but for some reason when i read the list using file_get_contents or fopen it does not work.

Comment: Path to the file is valid? Check `$myfile = fopen('list.txt', "r") or die ("HERE SHOULD BE A MESSAGE");`

Comment: And notice that the `fread` return string so you also want to `explode` it before merging and use as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully sure what you are trying to achieve here, but you have few problems:

1) selectedColor

should be $selectedColor

2) loading of the "array".

You cannot simply load a text and expect php to guess the format. If you want to load the file and treat it as an array you need to instruct php to do so.

In your example you can for example split the text and trim unwanted chars:

```
  $list = explode(',', $list);
  array_walk($list, function(&$elem) {
    $elem = trim($elem, ' \'');
  });
```

3) $selectedColor = $bg0[$i];

Replace:

```
$selectedColor = "$bg0[$i]";
```

with:

```
$selectedColor = $bg0[$i];
```

4) array push

This line is incorrect:

```
$bg0 = array($list ,'yellow'); // array of colors
```

Replace it with:

```
$bg0 = array_merge($list, ['yellow']); // array of colors
```

If you want to operate on a single array you can use `array_push` but then be sure to change the variable which you use later.

So for example:

```
<?php

  //$list = file_get_contents('list.txt'); //Tested without fopen

  $myfile = fopen('list.txt', "r") or die ("");

  $list = fread($myfile,filesize('list.txt'));

  $list = explode(',', $list);
  array_walk($list, function(&$elem) {
    $elem = trim($elem, ' \'');
  });

  $bg0 = array_merge($list , ['yellow']); // array of colors

  fclose($myfile);

  $i = rand(0, count($bg0)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedColor = $bg0[$i]; // set variable equal to which random color was chosen

  echo $selectedColor;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string into an array by using `explode()` and then to add additional elements if needed:

```
    $list = fread($myfile,filesize('list.txt'));
    fclose($myfile);

    $bg0 = explode(', ',str_replace("'","",$list));
    $bg0[] = 'yellow';
    $i = rand(0, count($bg0)-1); // generate random number size of the array
    $selectedColor = "$bg0[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random color was chosen

    echo $selectedColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to split the input values. This can be simply done by a regex.
- Afterwards add 'yellow' to the list
- Select the random color

```php
$data = "'red', 'blue', 'green'";
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $data, $matches);
$list = $matches[1];

$list[] = 'yellow';
$i = rand(0, count($list)-1);
$selectedColor = $list[$i];

echo $selectedColor;
```